# Select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?

Tags: sql

Table A

Column B : AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF

Table C

Column D : AA,BB,CC,GG,KK,MM

I need data from Table A which is not Present in Table C

Output Should be : DD,EE,FF

Tried Following :

```
Select A.B from A
Left Join C on A.B = C.D
where A.B not in(Select C from D)
```

Comment: Well "C from D" is backward, right?

Answer (score 3):

just don't do the join

```
select B
from A
where B not in(Select C from D)
```

You were trying to make it to complicated

Answer (score 2):

`not exists` springs to mind: it *might* be more efficient than `not in`, and it is `null`-safe, while `not in` is not (if any of the value returned by the `not in` subquery is `null`, all rows in the outer query will be returned, which is presumably not what you want):

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from c where a.b = c.d)
```

Or, in the spirit of your original query, you can go for the anti-`left join`:

```
select a.*
from a
left join c on a.b = c.d
where c.d is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of an anti-join:

```
select A.B 
from A
left join C on A.B = C.D
where C.D is null
```